# How to assign ByteSerialize attribute/length as a variable

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm creating models with different types and length which are used as a request/response to/from an API.

```
    [ByteSerialize(1)]
    public string ByteLength { get; set; }

    [ByteSerialize()]
    public string Byte { get; set; }
```

I would like first to get the ByteLength that comes from the API and them to pass it to the [ByteSerialize(?)]

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are inert - there's no magic way of getting things to happen automagically. Additionally, attributes are *usually* considered only as metadata in the IL, and as such: the parameters for them must be expressed as constants, not as runtime values. Obviously this changes if you only ever create the attributes as objects, not as metadata, but: your example shows metadata.

To do what you want, you *could* do it manually, i.e. have some *method* on `ByteSerializeAttribute`, and when your code detects (via `PropertyInfo`) that the attribute is there, use something like:

```
var value = property.GetValue(obj);
attrib.SomeMethod(obj, value); // or whatever you need
```